# Dynamically create import statements from src's inside a JSON file for webpack build

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I have an example JSON file like the following:

**menu.json**

```
{
  "0":{
      "img":"./101 cup noodles.png"
  },
  "1":{
      "img":"./102 cup noodles with beef.png"
  },
  "2":{
      "img":"./103 cup noodles with egg.png"
  },
  "3":{
      "img":"./104 cup noodles with shrimp.png"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to dynamically create import statements for each of the image links inside the JSON file for webpack to build?

I would like to avoid having to write an individual import for each image at the top of my javascript file especially if there are hundreds of items. E.g:

**menu.js**

```
import img0 from './101 cup noodles.png'
import img1 from './102 cup noodles with beef.png'
import img2 from './103 cup noodles with egg.png'
import img3 from './104 cup noodles with shrimp.png'
```

I have tried dynamically making the import statements with named fields and a for loop but learned that import statements need to be top level so unfortunately the following did not work:

**menu.js**

```
import data from './menu.json'

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    import ['img' + Object.keys(data)[i]] from data[i]['img'];
}
```

At the moment I am using the loop above to console log all of my import statements and just copy+pasting them into the top of my code but that seems extremely inelegant and I am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the properties of the object with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then map through the array and construct the string.

```js
const obj = {
  "0":{
      "img":"./101 cup noodles.png"
  },
  "1":{
      "img":"./102 cup noodles with beef.png"
  },
  "2":{
      "img":"./103 cup noodles with egg.png"
  },
  "3":{
      "img":"./104 cup noodles with shrimp.png"
  }
}

const res = Object.keys(obj).map(e => `import ${Object.keys(obj[e])[0] + e} from '${obj[e].img}'`).join('\n')

console.log(res)
```

Comment: That is essentially what I'm doing now and then taking that string and copy+pasting to the top of my javascript file. I was wondering if there was a way to get the imports done without needing the copy+paste step.

Comment: @Cambuchi not that I know of